Nginx Proxy Manager return Apache Default Page
I've issue to configure Nginx Proxy Manager with zabbix, nextcloud, Proxmox. I've a ndd.tld on OVH. NPM is installed on VM with Docker on Proxmox. It's works good for NPM, Portainer, grafana, HomeAssistant on LAN and WAN. But I don't succeed to configure it for Zabbix, Nextcloud,Pihole and Proxmox. When I try to connect to zabbix.ndd.tld, I've Apache default page.
Zabbix is on a LXC with Grafana. Nextcloud and Pihole are also on LXC, one for each.
enter image description here
Apache conf from Nextcloud :
`Alias /nextcloud "/var/www/nextcloud/"
<Directory /var/www/nextcloud/>
Require all granted
AllowOverride All
Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  
    Dav off
  
`
Thanks.
I tried to configure also Redirect Host on NPM without success.
